# What did Dickens mean by the phrase, 'In which heathen state of mind...' in The Haunted House?

Tags: meaning-in-context, charles-dickens

> If this should meet the eye of the gentleman who favoured me with these disclosures, I trust he will excuse my confessing that the sight of the rising sun, and the contemplation of the magnificent Order of the vast Universe, made me impatient of them. In a word, I was so impatient of them, that I was mightily glad to get out at the next station, and to exchange these clouds and vapours for the free air of Heaven.
>
> By that time it was a beautiful morning. As I walked away among such leaves as had already fallen from the golden, brown, and russet trees; and as I looked around me on the wonders of Creation, and thought of the steady, unchanging, and harmonious laws by which they are sustained; the gentleman’s spiritual intercourse seemed to me as poor a piece of journey-work as ever this world saw. **In which heathen state of mind, I came within view of the house**, and stopped to examine it attentively.
>
> <sup>Charles Dickens, [*The Haunted House*](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks/fr100113.txt)</sup>

Comment: Good question since he is going on about _wonders of Creation_

Comment: Could it mean "in _that_ heathen state of mind", or "in _such a_ heathen state of mind"? I've admittedly never seen _which_ used in this way.

Comment: Which part of the bolded sentence are you wondering about? "Heathen"?

Comment: of course, isn't that obvious?

Comment: No, because the answer you excepted was originally talking about "which" until they edited it to tack on a note about "heathen".

Comment: I didn't understand the phrase as a whole, but I guess you can say that first which and then heathen were my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [American Heritage Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/which) offers the definition for *which*:

> Being the one or ones previously mentioned or implied

Thus, you might read the phrase as *In a heathen state of mind (such as I have just described), I came within view of the house...*

The dictionary offers a clearer example:

> It started to rain, at which point we ran.

This seems to be a similar use; the only difference is that the antecedent of *which* here spans multiple sentences.

The descriptor *heathen* here refers to the narrator's disregard for whatever *spiritual intercourse* the gentleman had been communicating to the narrator.

Comment: so it means: thinking about these things, I came within view of the house? and it has nothing to do with religions what so ever?

Comment: so he is just referring to what he has just said AND labeling it heathen because somehow he forgot about god and everything and was free to think for himself and see for himself like a heathen?

Comment: @Hamed I've added a brief explanation for *heathen* as well; I think my explanation is at least partly in line with your own interpretation.

Comment: Your reference to  “the narrator's disregard for holy matters such as *the magnificent Order of the vast Universe*” is in error.  To the contrary, it was “the sight of the rising sun, and the contemplation of the magnificent Order of the vast Universe” that made him impatient of the gentleman's disclosures; and it was viewing the wonders of Creation and thinking of harmonious laws that made “the gentleman’s spiritual intercourse” seem so poor.

Comment: @jwpat7 Ah, yes, I see now how I misread the first two sentences. Thanks; I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

Another paragraph or six of context would have been a bit more illuminating, I think, to set up the full exchange between the narrator and the unnamed gentleman.

I believe that Dickens is using *heathen* first in the sense of *uncivilized, uncultured*; the narrator is in a "heathen state of mind" because he is acknowledging himself to be rudely dismissive of "the gentleman's spiritual discourse" (which occurred just before the excerpt given).

It does, however, also bear the sense that he is a disbeliever in the content of the "spiritual discourse", particularly in regard to the existence and manifestations of ghosts and spirits; the use of the word *heathen* in particular draws an amusing juxtaposition between the disbelief in ghosts and the belief in the God of Creation and Nature.

So, while the narrator was busy thinking rude thoughts about the gentleman on the train and admiring the wonders of a beautiful morning, he came within view of the house.

Comment: *Heathen* to Dickens and his readers meant specifically *unChristian*; the gentleman on the train, offering 'spiritual intercourse' was clearly preaching (officially or otherwise) and being impatient with him, preferring Nature and God to words and the Church, is clearly heathen in this sense (tongue-in-cheek, of course).

Comment: Actually if you check out the text (available at project Gutenberg), the gentleman on the train was carrying on about all manner of "communications" with the dead, and being quite overbearingly superior about it.